# A SQL query to get info from multiple tables

Tags: sql

OK, I'm an absolute beginner in SQL and I got one task to solve and I'm stuck, so I need help on your ideas how to get the required results.

I have 2 tables - first one is `PARENTS`, with the following data:

```
ID         Name          Age
1          John          25
2          Peter         28
3          Anny          30
4          Jack          32
```

and the second table is `CHILDRENS`, with the following data:

```
children_id           parent_id        name         age
1                        1             mary          5
2                        1             Susanne       4
3                        2             stephen       12
4                        4             Kevin         7
```

What SQL command can be used to get following result:

```
id               parent name          number of childrens
1                  John                      2
2                  Peter                     1
3                  Anny                      0
4                  Jack                      1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Are you using MySQL and/or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN, with GROUP BY and count(*).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
select PARENTS.id,PARENTS.name,count(CHILDRENS.name)
from PARENTS left join CHILDRENS on PARENTS.id=CHILDRENS.parent_id
group by PARENTS.id,PARENTS.name
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jarlh in comments, Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` + `Group by`

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       Count(parent_id) as number_of_childrens
FROM   PARENTS p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILDRENS c
                    ON c.parent_id = p.ID 
Group by p.id,
         p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.id, p.name, count(p.id) as number_of_childrens
from parents p
left join childrens c
on p.parent_id = c.parent_id
group by p.id, p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID
    , A.name AS parent_name
    , COUNT(B.children_id) AS number_of_children
FROM PARENTS AS A
LEFT JOIN CHILDRENS AS B
ON A.ID = B.parent_id
GROUP BY A.ID
    , A.name
```

A left join, count and group by.